# Is it correct to take the conditional expectation on both sides?

Tags: conditional-probability, expectation

Let $X$ be an arbitrary random variable.
Given an equation l.h.s. = r.h.s. does this imply $E[l.h.s.| X=x] = E[r.h.s.|X=x]$?

Cheers.

Comment: I doubt that the statement of your question reflects what you are trying to prove.  Are the "lhs - rhs" random variables?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, if the equation means that the two sides are always  equal to each other. It's the same as saying: if two functions are identically equal, then their integrals are equal.